# WSO2 EI611 Kafka Connector Inbound Endpoint error with CAR & Console

Tags: wso2, apache-kafka, connector, wso2-esb

https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESBCONNECTORS/Configuring+Kafka_2.12-0.11.0.0+Operations
https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESBCONNECTORS/Configuring+Kafka+Inbound+Operations
https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESBCONNECTORS/Kafka_2.12-0.11.0.0+Connector+and+Inbound+Endpoint

There's no directory structure like the one mentioned in one of above documentation links:

> To configure the Kafka inbound endpoint, copy the following client
>   libraries from the /lib directory to the
>   /repository/components/lib directory.

I configured Kafka InboundEndpoint with EI611 on management console and received this error in logs :

> org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Exception while loading
>   Zookeeper JAAS login context 'Client'...... Caused by:
>   java.lang.SecurityException: java.io.IOException:
>   C:\WSO2EI~1.1\bin..\repository\conf\identity\jaas.conf (No such file
>   or directory)

Alternatively, I developed a Inbound endpoint from tooling and deploy the CAR file, I get the following error :

> [2017-10-20 18:15:11,138] [] ERROR - KAFKAPollingConsumer  Error in
>   Creating Kafka Consumer Connector [2017-10-20 18:15:13,133] []  INFO -
>   KAFKAMessageListener Creating Kafka Consumer Connector... [2017-10-20
>   18:15:13,134] [] ERROR - KAFKAMessageListener  Error in Creating Kafka
>   Consumer Connector.requirement failed: socket.timeout.ms should always
>   be at least fetch.wait.max.ms to prevent unnecessary socket timeouts
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed:
>   socket.timeout.ms should always be at least fetch.wait.max.ms to
>   prevent unnecessary socket timeouts
>           at scala.Predef$.require(Predef.scala:277)
>           at kafka.consumer.ConsumerConfig.(ConsumerConfig.scala:153)
>           at kafka.consumer.ConsumerConfig.(ConsumerConfig.scala:110)
>           at org.wso2.carbon.inbound.endpoint.protocol.kafka.KAFKAMessageListener.createKafkaConsumerConnector(KAFKAMessageListener.java:56)
>           at org.wso2.carbon.inbound.endpoint.protocol.kafka.KAFKAPollingConsumer.poll(KAFKAPollingConsumer.java:145)
>           at org.wso2.carbon.inbound.endpoint.protocol.kafka.KAFKAPollingConsumer.execute(KAFKAPollingConsumer.java:116)
>           at org.wso2.carbon.inbound.endpoint.protocol.kafka.KAFKATask.taskExecute(KAFKATask.java:48)
>           at org.wso2.carbon.inbound.endpoint.common.InboundTask.execute(InboundTask.java:45)
>           at org.wso2.carbon.mediation.ntask.NTaskAdapter.execute(NTaskAdapter.java:98)
>           at org.wso2.carbon.ntask.core.impl.TaskQuartzJobAdapter.execute(TaskQuartzJobAdapter.java:67)
>           at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:213)
>           at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<inboundEndpoint name="KafkaReceiver" onError="ErrorKafkaSeq" protocol="kafka" sequence="InKafkaSeq" suspend="false" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <parameters>
        <parameter name="interval">1000</parameter>
        <parameter name="sequential">true</parameter>
        <parameter name="coordination">true</parameter>
        <parameter name="zookeeper.connect">localhost:2181</parameter>
        <parameter name="group.id">sampleGroupID</parameter>
        <parameter name="content.type">application/xml</parameter>
        <parameter name="consumer.type">highlevel</parameter>
        <parameter name="topics">sampleTopic</parameter>
        <parameter name="socket.timeout.ms">0</parameter>
        <parameter name="auto.commit.enable">false</parameter>
        <parameter name="auto.offset.reset">smallest</parameter>
        <parameter name="exclude.internal.topics">false</parameter>
        <parameter name="partition.assignment.strategy">roundrobin</parameter>
        <parameter name="offsets.storage">zookeeper</parameter>
        <parameter name="dual.commit.enabled">false</parameter>
    </parameters>
</inboundEndpoint>
```

Comment: Anybody from WSO2, even care to reply this? You claim that this is the official user/dev community, but did not care to respond....

Answer (score 0):

I hope the above documentation is written based on the WSO2 ESB. If you are using EI please copy your all relevant 3rd party libraries to /lib.
Please add the jaas.conf[1] file to the directory (/repository/conf/identity/)

[1]https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/jre/api/security/jaas/spec/com/sun/security/auth/module/Krb5LoginModule.html

Comment: Thanks, I copied all the relevant libraries, like you said. jaas.conf, whats the minimum parameters to set? The link points to various settings and do I have to construct the details, by reading the entire spec? is there a baisc sample of jaas.conf that can be used ?